# Missing object Reference in redefined list using concerning extended items

Tags: c#, project-management

He everybody,

I'm trying to setup a project management class.
In order to see if somthing in the data changed i want to implement events on the lower level of the programming structure. I have some Classes extending the ProjectComponent Class. The base class has an event and event throwing methode, which the childcomponents can use.
Now I have a couple of custom list (nameley eList) in the project object.
Because all the child component have a common parent, ProjectComponent, i would like my custom list object (eList) to subscribe to the event when an object is added and unsubscribe when removed.

However when trying to prog this, i received the following error:

> 'ProjectComponent' does not contain a
>   definition for 'itemChanged' and no
>   extension method 'itemChanged'
>   accepting a first argument of type
>   'ProjectComponent'

Which is kind of wierd seeing as the class clearly has that public field.

Here is a the code:

```
public class ProjectComponent
{
    public event ItemChanged itemChanged;

    public void throwItemChangedEvent(ItemChangedEventArgs Arguments)
    {
        if (itemChanged != null)
            itemChanged(new Object(), Arguments);
    }
}

public class eList<ProjectComponent> : IList<ProjectComponent>
{
    List<ProjectComponent> internalList = new List<ProjectComponent>();
    public override void Add(ProjectComponent Item)
    {
        this.internalList.Add(Item);
        Item.itemChanged += new ItemChanged(ItemChanged_Handler);
    }

    private void ItemChanged_Handler(object sender, ItemChangedEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        //do stuff here
    }
}
```

An example how it would be called is:

```
public eList<ChildClass> Children = new eList<ChildClass>();
```

The idea is that when an object in the list is edited the list object recieve an object like so:

```
Children.childstring = "anything";
```

At the moment the field inside the Children object is changed an event could be recieved.

My question is simply what am i doing wrong, why cant i suscribe to the ProjectComponent event inside the eList class?
Or does anyone know a better way to achive the same results?

Thanks in Advance,

Harry

Edit: Definition of ItemChanged delagate:

```
public delegate void ItemChanged(object sender, ItemChangedEventArgs eventArgs);
public class ItemChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    private String p_CallStack;

    public String CallStack
    {
        get { return this.p_CallStack; }
        set { this.p_CallStack = value; }
    }

    public ItemChangedEventArgs()
    {
        p_CallStack = "";
    }

    public ItemChangedEventArgs(String StackStart)
    {
        p_CallStack = StackStart;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the definition of `ItemChanged`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have 2 errors:

1.

in [generic class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sz6zd40f%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) definition you must use variables not existing classes:

<s>`public class eList<ProjectComponent>: ...`</s>

**-->** `public class eList<T>: ...`

in your case you want to do:

```
public class eList : IList<ProjectComponent>
```

2.

```
Item.itemChanged += new Item.itemChanged(ItemChanged_Handler);
```

`new Item.itemChanged` has no meaning, you have to use the underlying delegate type of your event:

```
Item.itemChanged += new ItemChanged(ItemChanged_Handler);
```

**N.B:**

your code does not respect at all design guidelines for c#

More informations here:[Naming Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzf533w0%28v=VS.71%29.aspx)

Comment: same error? Do you have somewhere else in your code a line with `..itemChanged(var)...` where the type of `var` is `ProjectComponent`?

Comment: Nope not that i could find :S

Comment: ive added the def of itemchanged delegate, ty btw :P

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be

```
Item.itemChanged += new ItemChanged(ItemChanged_Handler);
```

Comment: sry for the double posting :S

Comment: ive added the def for itemchanged delegate :P